# Get data from Excel files using SQL query in Java

Tags: java, sql, excel, arraylist, apache-poi

I have Excel file in that i have three sheets. I am using fillo api to query excel file using SQL Queries i can get recordset of two excel sheets dynamically, but when i try to fetch the third recordset the previous values are erasing. what i want is i need to have all the values of three recordsets in one row.

For Example: [101, 17000, AD_VP, Administration Vice President, 15000, 30000, AD_VP]
Here, 101, 17000, AD_VP are from one table and remaining are from another table but i can't get the third table values in same row.

I want this to be done in dynamic way.

I tried below code, it is working for two tables but not for more than two.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fillo fillo = new Fillo();
        Connection connection = null;
        Recordset recordset = null;
        Recordset recordset1 = null;
        
        //String originalQuery = "SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEES.SALARY, JOBS.JOB_TITLE, JOBS.MIN_SALARY, JOBS.MAX_SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES INNER JOIN JOBS ON  EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID = JOBS.JOB_ID";
        String originalQuery = "SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEES.SALARY, DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, LOCATIONS.POSTAL_CODE, LOCATIONS.CITY FROM EMPLOYEES INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS ON  EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID   INNER JOIN LOCATIONS ON  DEPARTMENTS.LOCATION_ID = LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID";
        try {
            //connection = fillo.getConnection("D:\\employeeJobs.xlsx");
            connection = fillo.getConnection("D:\\MultipleSheets.xlsx");
            
            String[] tableNames = MultipleSeparateJoins.extractTableNames(originalQuery);
            List<String> commonColumns = null;
            List<String> addColumns = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0; i<tableNames.length-1; i++) {
                String[] secondTablename = tableNames;
                commonColumns = MultipleSeparateJoins.extractCommonColumns(originalQuery, tableNames[i], secondTablename[i+1]);
                addColumns.addAll(commonColumns);
            }
            System.out.println(addColumns);
            String query = "";
            String query1 = "";
            ArrayList<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fieldValues = new ArrayList<>();
            
            for(int i=0; i<tableNames.length-1; i++) {
                query = MultipleSeparateJoins.extractQuery(originalQuery, tableNames[i]);
                recordset = connection.executeQuery(query);
                query1 = MultipleSeparateJoins.extractQuery(originalQuery, tableNames[i+1]);
                recordset1 = connection.executeQuery(query1);
                if(fieldNames.containsAll(recordset.getFieldNames())) {
                    fieldNames.addAll(recordset1.getFieldNames());
                }else {
                    fieldNames.addAll(recordset.getFieldNames());
                    fieldNames.addAll(recordset1.getFieldNames());  
                }
                while(recordset.next()) {
                    ArrayList<String> rowValues = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(String fieldName : recordset.getFieldNames()) {
                        rowValues.add(recordset.getField(fieldName));
                    }
                    while(recordset1.next()) {
                        if(recordset1.getField(addColumns.get(i)).equals(recordset.getField(addColumns.get(i)))) {
                            for(String fieldName : recordset1.getFieldNames()) {
                                rowValues.add(recordset1.getField(fieldName));
                            }
                            fieldValues.add(rowValues);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    recordset1.moveFirst();
                }
                
            }
            System.out.println("Total Number of Records are: "+fieldValues.size());
            for(String fieldName : fieldNames) {
                System.out.print(fieldName + "\t"+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
            
            for(ArrayList<String> row : fieldValues) {
                for(String value : row) {
                    System.out.print(value + "\t"+"\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            connection.close();
            recordset.close();
        }
    }
    
    public static String[] extractTableNames(String originalQuery) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bFROM\\s+\\w+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("\\bJOIN\\s+\\w+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(originalQuery);
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(originalQuery);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(matcher.find()) {
            String tableName = matcher.group().replaceAll("(?i)FROM\\s+", "");
            sb.append(tableName).append(",");
        }
        while(matcher1.find()) {
            String tableName = matcher1.group().replaceAll("(?i)JOIN\\s+", "");
            sb.append(tableName).append(",");
        }
        String[] tableNames = sb.toString().split(",");
        return tableNames;
    }
    
    public static String extractQuery(String originalQuery, String tableName) {     
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + tableName + "\\.\\w+"/*"(?i)SELECT\\s+(.*?)\\bFROM\\s+"*/);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(originalQuery);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String column = matcher.group();
            sb.append(column).append(", ");
            /*String selectClause = matcher.group(1); // Extract the text between SELECT and FROM
            String[] columns = selectClause.split(",");
            for (String column : columns) {
                String trimmedColumn = column.trim();
                if (trimmedColumn.startsWith(tableName + ".")) {
                    sb.append(trimmedColumn).append(", ");
                }
            }*/
        }

        // Remove the trailing comma and space from the extracted column names
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length());
        }

        // Build the extracted query with the extracted column names
        String extractedQuery = "SELECT " + sb.toString() + " FROM " + tableName;

        return extractedQuery;
        
    }
    
    public static List<String> extractCommonColumns(String originalQuery, String tableName, String secondTablename){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bJOIN\\s+" + secondTablename + "\\s+ON\\s+" + tableName + "\\.\\w+\\s*=\\s*" + secondTablename + "\\.\\w+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(originalQuery);
        List<String> commonColumns = new ArrayList<>();

        if (matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group();
            String[] columns = match.split("\\s*=\\s*"); // splitting based on = (equals)
            if (columns.length == 2) {
                String[] parts1 = columns[0].split("\\s+"); // splitting based on white space 
                String[] parts2 = columns[1].split("\\s+"); 
                if (parts1.length > 0 && parts2.length > 0) {
                    String[] subParts = parts1[3].split("\\."); // splitting based on . (dot)
                    String[] subParts1 = parts2[0].split("\\.");
                    commonColumns.add(subParts[1]); 
                    //commonColumns.add(subParts1[1]); 
                }
            }
        }

        return commonColumns;
    }
```